# CLIPS - How to get the value of a specific fact?

Tags: if-statement, clips

I wanted to create an if-then-else function using CLIPS but I'm having an issue with my conditional statement.

Sample Facts:

```
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (green-peppers yes)
```

Is it possible to get the value of green-peppers(yes) so I can set a condition like this?

```
(if (eq <fact-1> "yes")
   then 
   (assert)
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (assert (green-peppers yes))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (green-peppers no))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> 
(deffunction need (?f)
   (bind ?v (nth$ 1 (fact-slot-value ?f implied)))
   (if (eq ?v yes)
      then TRUE
      else FALSE))
CLIPS> (need 1)
TRUE
CLIPS> (need 2)
FALSE
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (deftemplate green-peppers (slot need))
CLIPS> (assert (green-peppers (need yes)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (green-peppers (need no)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> 
(deffunction need (?f)
   (if (eq (fact-slot-value ?f need) yes)
      then TRUE
      else FALSE))
CLIPS> (need 1)
TRUE
CLIPS> (need 2)
FALSE
CLIPS>
```